# If - Statement Error

Tags: java, android, if-statement

[SOLVED] shall i delete this post now?
[SOLUTION] to make the input more comfortable to use i told the program to `input.setText("")`. This was causing the error obviously. Thanks to all of you :).

i am new to android and java and i got a problem with my if statement. Every time "MainActivity.help equals 1, the program crashes and i don't know how to fix this. Would be really cool, if someone could check the code below:

```
if (MainActivity.help == 1) {

  int x = randomnumber;
  int y = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());

  int diffrence = Math.abs(x - y);
  if (diffrence < 3) {
  imageb.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
}
```

MainActivity.help is a public static int 
randomnumber is an integer too 
and input is an editText

Thank you for any help and sorry about my bad English.
Tim

This is the message i receive:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.tim.greroderkleiner, PID: 4487
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                      at com.example.tim.greroderkleiner.MainActivity.confirm(MainActivity.java:228)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

is this saying anything to anyone? :)

Comment: Try using a debugger? Also you should get error output in your console. Please include that.

Comment: *Everytime "MainActivity.help equals 1, the program crashes* ? WOW That's just made my day . Its your code which is crashing not the `if` statement .

Comment: Almost certainly because input doesn't have numeric data in it, but impossible to tell without the log error.  Also, keeping static variables on an activity like that is an almost 100% sign that your program is poorly written and you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct. You are missing a closing brace.

Comment: Please post the log of the exception.

Comment: is this the log you need?

Comment: @TimH., yes, that's the one. Read what it says: `Invalid int ""`. Your input is empty, yet you commanded to parse it into a number, which can't be done. This is the reason your program crashes, not some `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you all, it works now :). Shall i delete this post now?

Comment: No u should upvote helpful answers and mark the answer that helped you to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the error, I bet you're hitting a `NullPointerException` at your `Integer.parseInt()` invocation. You should check your input to make sure you're not trying to call `.toString()` on `null`.

EDIT: thank you for posting your output. The issue is clear:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
```

This means you're trying to cast `""` to an integer, which will throw an error. You'll need to check that your input text is not an empty string as well as for nullity:

```
String inputText = input.getText();
if (inputText != null && inputText != "") { 
    int y = Integer.parseInt(inputText.toString()); //probably don't need the toString()
    /* rest of your code */
} else { 
    /* inputText is null */
}
```

Comment: This is a problem i was facing before, but thank you for your answer. I posted the error above if this is helping you. :)

Comment: @TimH. Thank you for posting the output. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (MainActivity.help == 1) {
  try {
    int x = randomnumber;
    int y;
    if(input.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
       int y = 0;
    } else {
       y = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
    }
    int diffrence = Math.abs(x - y);
    if (diffrence < 3) {
      imageb.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Do nothing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent entered any text in the textbox and trying to parse the empty string to int and thats causing the error.

```
  int y = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
```

Try checking if the input is not null and also check if the entered string is all digits before parsing to int.

```
String x=input.getText().toString()
if(!x.equals("") && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(x))
   int y = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
```

Comment: i got an if statement before so that the code above will just execute if the editText is not empty.

Comment: ya..u shoudnt go to the if statemtent itself if the input is null...answer is just giving an idea of what needs to be done